# Javascript email regex matching

Tags: javascript, regex

Please see the Javascript code below. The else if block which is doing a check for email pattern is not allowing any of the email ids . What does the `match()` function return? Please help.

Used test()

empty field :working fine
wron mail id : working fine 
Correct email id : not working

```
var pattern = new RegExp("/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/");
   if(!accountantEmail){
       $("#infoTextMsg").hide();
       $("#accountantEmailNoDataErr").show();
       $("#accountantEmailInvalidFormat").hide();
       $("#accountant_email").focus();
       return false;
   }
   else if(!(pattern.test(accountantEmail))){
       $("#accountantEmailInvalidFormat").show();
       $("#infoTextMsg").hide();
       $("#accountantEmailNoDataErr").hide();
       $("#accountant_email").focus();
       return false;
   }
```

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address

Comment: What exactly do you want to validate? That they've entered something that looks like an e-mail address or that they've actually entered a working e-mail address that they have access to? If it's the former, use a regular expression. If it's the latter, check it has an `@` symbol in it then send a verification e-mail for them to confirm it actually works.

Comment: anthony , it is showing invalid email id inspite of me entering a valid one

Comment: Your regex will reject a lot of valid address, have a look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Valid_email_addresses

Comment: TLDs may have much more than 3 character long. Here is the list of TLDs: http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt

Comment: M42 , at least something like "kulkarni.karthik@gmail.com " should succeed isn't it

Answer (score 0):

Javascript match returns an array containing the matches.

Here's the regular expression I use:

```
var pattern = "[-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+@[-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}";

if(!(accountantEmail.match(pattern))) {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For `validation` scenarios, you should use the `RegExp#test` function.

```
var pattern = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;

if (!pattern.test(accountantEmail)) {
    $("#accountantEmailInvalidFormat").show();
    $("#infoTextMsg").hide();
    $("#accountantEmailNoDataErr").hide();
    $("#accountant_email").focus();
    return false;
}
```

As commented on the other posts, the `match` function is intended for group capturing.

Also note that you were specifying your `pattern` with an `/` on it's beginning. This isn't necessary if you're specifying a RegExp as a string.

Comment: I tried this but when i enter an email id it gets returned from the first if block and always gives me "Please enter a mail id "message which i have mostly coded for null validation

Comment: Try changing your first `if` condition to: `if (!accountantEmail){`

Comment: Have you debugged your javascript to check the `accountantEmail` value? It might be really empty for some reason.

Comment: TypeError: accountantEmail.test is not a function says the chrome console

Comment: No, check my snippet again. The `test` function belongs to the RegExp object, not your string.

Comment: (pattern.test(accountantEmail)  should be the syantax . I am so dumb :)

Comment: the code looks like this now . If i give a valid email id it says please enter a valid one . 
var pattern = new RegExp("<pattern>");
   if(!accountantEmail){
    $("#infoTextMsg").hide();
    $("#accountantEmailNoDataErr").show();
    $("#accountantEmailInvalidFormat").hide();
    $("#accountant_email").focus();
    return false;
   }
   else if(!(pattern.test(accountantEmail))){
    $("#accountantEmailInvalidFormat").show();
    $("#infoTextMsg").hide();
    $("#accountantEmailNoDataErr").hide();
    $("#accountant_email").focus();
    return false;
   }

Comment: Again... what is your `accountantEmail` variable value?